# How to check if QTreeWidgetItem is checked or unchecked? (PyQt4/Python)

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, signals-slots, qtreewidget

I have created a QTreeWidget with Items (parent, Child) and i have set up a check box (As Shown in the code). When an item is checked, i wanted to execute a command using SQL database. (I know the SQL bit), but i wanted to know how i can find out if an item is checked or unchecked? Would i need to create a use signals?

The code is as follows:

```
#Form ui
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.FilterList = QTreeWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.FilterList)

        status = self.statusBar()
        status.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        status.showMessage("Ready", 5000)
        self.setWindowTitle("Form")
        self.generateData()

    def createMenusAndToolbars(self):
        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        fileToolbar = self.addToolBar("File")
        fileToolbar.setObjectName("FileToolbar")
        for icon, text in (("new", "&New..."), ("open", "&Open..."),
                ("save", "&Save"), ("save", "Save &As..."),
                (None, None), ("quit", "&Quit")):
            if icon is None:
                fileMenu.addSeparator()
            else:
                action = QAction(QIcon(":/file{}.png".format(icon)),
                                 text, self)
                if icon == "quit":
                    self.connect(action, SIGNAL("triggered()"),
                                 self.close)
                elif text != "Save &As...":
                    fileToolbar.addAction(action)
                fileMenu.addAction(action)

        editMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Edit")
        editToolbar = self.addToolBar("Edit")
        editToolbar.setObjectName("EditToolbar")
        for icon, text in (("add", "&Add..."), ("edit", "&Edit..."),
                           ("delete", "&Remove")):
            action = QAction(QIcon(":/edit{}.png".format(icon)),
                             text, self)
            editToolbar.addAction(action)
            editMenu.addAction(action)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.okToContinue():
            settings = QSettings()
            settings.setValue("MainWindow/Geometry", self.saveGeometry())
            settings.setValue("MainWindow/State", self.saveState())
            settings.setValue("MessageSplitter", self.QuestionSplitter.saveState())
            settings.setValue("MainSplitter", self.mainSplitter.saveState())
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def okToContinue(self):
        return True

    def generateData(self):
        self.FilterList.setColumnCount(1)
        self.FilterList.setHeaderLabels(["Filter Questions"])
        ViewNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["View All"])
        ViewNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Checked)
        DifficultyNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Difficulty"])
        TopicNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Topic"])
        TypeNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Type"])
        self.FilterList.addTopLevelItem(ViewNode)
        self.FilterList.addTopLevelItem(DifficultyNode)
        self.FilterList.addTopLevelItem(TopicNode)
        self.FilterList.addTopLevelItem(TypeNode)
        EasyNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Easy"])
        EasyNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        NormalNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Normal"])
        NormalNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        HardNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Hard"])
        HardNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        MultipleNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Multiple Choice"])
        MultipleNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        ShortNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Short Answer"])
        ShortNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        NumericNode = QTreeWidgetItem(["Numerical Answer"])
        NumericNode.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic1_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Multiples, Factors, Primer Numbers and Prime Factors"])
        Topic1_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic2_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Fractions (+-x and ÷) non-calculator approach"])
        Topic2_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic3_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Significant Figures, Decimal Places"])
        Topic3_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic4_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Scatter Graphs and Correlation"])
        Topic4_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic5_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Directed Numbers and Coordinates"])
        Topic5_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic6_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Representing Numbers by letters/Algebra"])
        Topic6_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic7_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Circle Circumference/Area"])
        Topic7_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic8_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Pie Charts and Averages"])
        Topic8_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic9_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Angles"])
        Topic9_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic10_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Breaking Brackets"])
        Topic10_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic11_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Percentages"])
        Topic11_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic12_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Measuring - Length, area, volume, weight, metric and imperial units"])
        Topic12_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic13_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Triangles"])
        Topic13_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic14_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Equations"])
        Topic14_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        Topic15_Node = QTreeWidgetItem(["Ratio"])
        Topic15_Node.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic1_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic2_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic3_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic4_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic5_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic6_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic7_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic8_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic9_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic10_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic11_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic12_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic13_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic14_Node)
        TopicNode.addChild(Topic15_Node)
        DifficultyNode.addChild(EasyNode)
        DifficultyNode.addChild(NormalNode)
        DifficultyNode.addChild(HardNode)
        TypeNode.addChild(MultipleNode)
        TypeNode.addChild(ShortNode)
        TypeNode.addChild(NumericNode)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

main()
```

Comment: It looks like `checkState()` returns whether or not it is checked (it is the getter). `setCheckState()` is the setter version of that function. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662020/how-to-implement-itemchecked-and-itemunchecked-signals-for-qtreewidget-in-pyqt4 and here: http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/QTreeWidgetItem/

Comment: Could you provide an example code as to how this would work?

Answer (score 7):

Connect a slot to the [itemChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#itemChanged) signal of the tree-widget, like this:

```
    self.FilterList.itemChanged.connect(self.handleItemChanged)
    ...


def handleItemChanged(self, item, column):
    if item.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        print('Item Checked')
    elif item.checkState(column) == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
        print('Item Unchecked')
```